# how to change font size of word document using .net

Tags: c#, fonts, spire.doc

I am working on a application using C# and Spire.Doc which saves the word document to specified format which includes logo at the header and specified font size and style.

Now I can paste logo at the header using spire.doc but I'm not able to change the **font** style and **size** of the whole document:

```
font size should be 10;
font should be: franklin gothic demi
```

Can someone please help me for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word(v=office.11).aspx).

This will allow you to do something like this:

```
var start = this.Content.Start;
var end = this.Content.End;

var docRange = this.Range(ref start, ref end).Select();

docRange.Font.Size = 10; 
docRange.Font.Name = "Franklin Gothic Demi";
```

For more detail see: [How to: Programmatically Format Text in Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b7k14a4.aspx).

**EDIT:**

To add an image to the header you need to do something like:

```
section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary]
       .Shapes
       .AddPicture(@"headerImage.jpg", left, top, width, height);
```

Or:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.LoadFromFile(@"C:\MyDoc.docx", FileFormat.Docx);
HeaderFooter header = doc.Sections[0].HeadersFooters.Header;
Image headerImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\headerImage.png");
header.Paragraphs[0].AppendPicture(logo).TextWrappingStyle = TextWrappingStyle.Tight;
```

Comment: Thank you so much...its working...now my doubt is can we add image into header of word document using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word??....please suggest me some solutions...thank in advance

Comment: @pavanbetageri I've edited answer to include information about adding an image. Can you be sure to accept as answer if this solved your problem? :)

Comment: @RagtimeWilly...sure..ill try this code today...thank you so much

Comment: @RagtimeWilly...its working, can i do the same using spire.doc for  entire word document??

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Spire.Doc](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/word-for-net-introduce.html#.VRFCXvmG_hk) :

```
        //Font name
        txtRange.CharacterFormat.FontName = "Century Gothic";

        //Size
        txtRange.CharacterFormat.FontSize = 15;

        //Underline
        txtRange.CharacterFormat.UnderlineStyle = UnderlineStyle.Dash;

        //Color
        txtRange.CharacterFormat.TextColor = Color.Brown;
        txtRange1.CharacterFormat.TextColor = Color.ForestGreen;
```

Comment: how can i do this for entire word document using spire.doc